# CMB Metabox and custom fields

Tags: wordpress

Sorry, I hope this is simple, but does Web Dev Studios Custom Metabox feature (https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) need to save the data to the custom fields?

Basically I have it installed and it works but none of the data entered is appearing in the custom fields box like on another site I have, is this going to cause an issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

sorry I dont have experience with that one. Use Advanced Custom Fields plugin. It'll be lot easier for you. you can even include it to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, CMB Automatically save the data and retrieve. you may made any mistake, please switch on wp-debug (wp-config.php) and see if you can see any error.

Advance custom field is an alternate solution which has Graphical User Interface. you can also use it.